# Any side effects of Initialisation and de-initialisation of STM32F0 MCU I2C pin frequently?

Tags: i2c, pins, timing

I have one port on my MCU and want to re-define its functionality.
Is it possible that something wrong/strange happens if I do it in my `main()` function?
I regularly switch the funtion of the pin in `millisec` jobs (eg. between I2C and UART)

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: @TonyM hmm not sure about your comment, but asking if changing purpos of a pin every ms have a strange results... I don't see this like a homework question or something that I would find on google. Thank you.

Comment: This is way too vague to answer in the abstract.  Feel free to provide enough details to turn it into an answerable question.

Comment: A starting point might be a part number and link to a spec.  The answer is probably different for different manufacturers and cores.

Comment: please tell more about external connections. Will there be some transmitter on the other side of UART? show us the schemtics. Let us know, why you want to do it too

Comment: Hmmm-ing aside, it's a polite, friendly version of 'write a much better question with details in it'. The other comments echo that.

Comment: @Umar external stuff does not mater. I was wondering only about how processor would handle it (arm stmf0 - I doubt that which exact model of ST cortex M0 maters), To be pore precise I was thinking of making my MCU a "bridge" between 2 different I2C lines (I do not want them to see each other) so I was thinking to make lets say pin 1,2 I2C1 for some time and after lets say 10ms change to I2C1 to pins eg. 5,6 (some controllers have same function on multiple pins). I hope this makes more sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is likely that something unexpected will happen. In your example, both I2C and a UART use the voltages on a pin to convey serial data. The pattern of 1s and 0s for a I2C transmission **might** look like a valid UART transmission, depending on the I2C and UART data rates.

There are certain situations where you can get away with using one pin for multiple functions, but these require very careful design.

Comment: THank you :) well uart/i2c was more like an example. what I am trying to do is use I2C1 at one moment at ping eg. 1,2 and after lets say 10ms disable it and enable I2C1 that is on pin eg. 5,6. (1,2 and 5,6 are I2C1 pins). I am trying to make my MCU as bridge between 2 different I2C lines, so they do not see each other.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just make sure to put the not-in-use pins in a benign state...don't allow a false clock pulse to occur.

Comment: Perfect thank you :)